# Need Help on Onedit function on GoogleScript ( Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

Sheet 1 I have a google script which populates data through fetch from SQL query.

I need a script where whatever Data populates on A1: A1000 should be automatically move to Sheet2 A1 cell.

Simple language, every 30 minutes the data will be populated in A column and i need that data to be moved to sheet 2 automatically as soon as its populate.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is but just in case you're thinking that the onEdit() will trigger when column1 data changes, you might want to read the section on simple triggers to learn that onEdit() is only triggered with a User makes an edit.

Comment: onEdit() is only triggered when data is edited by the user.

Answer (score 0):

### As a workaround:

- you can create a secondary spreadsheet
- incorporate into a cell the Google Sheets function `IMPORTRANGE` to import the primary sheet
- Attach to the secondary spreadsheet a script with an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange`

### Why?

Because update of a spreadsheet by an SQL query will not fire an Apps Script trigger (see [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)). However, the `IMPORTRANGE` function can fire the `onChange` trigger when the range updates.

**A sample script that implementing the desired functionality, if fired by an `onChange` trigger:**

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data=sheet1.getRange("A1:A1000").getValues();
  sheet2.getRange("A1:A1000").setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Once its moved, Will it get deleted from sheet one. I need the data to be deleted after kits moved to sheet2

Comment: If you delete the data, you will also delete the `IMPORTRANGE` formula, so no new data will be imported after this.